# Manage multiple webview in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development and I'm searching the best way to manage multiple webview at the same time.

My goal is to create a simple web browser with a small menu listing my opened "tab" and replace my content section inside my layout by the user's selection. I don't want to have visible tab like Chrome and the stock browser on a tablet.

What is the best way to manage multiple view, switch between them and keep their state ?

Should I use multiple fragment (each one containing a webview) and FragmentManager to replace the content ? 
Manage manually a framelayout by removing and adding the selected webview ?

**UPDATE**:

I played with Fragment today and I made a quick test project.
Here some code:
My Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private WebFragment f1;
    private WebFragment f2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    f1 = new WebFragment();
    f2 = new WebFragment();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fff, f1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    f1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
    f2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");


}

private void switchFragment(int id) {
    FragmentTransaction trx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (id == 1) {
        trx.replace(R.id.fff, f1);
    } else if (id == 2) {
        trx.replace(R.id.fff, f2);
    }
    trx.commit();

}
...
}
```

My Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/ww"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>

public class WebFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "WebFragment";
    private View v = null;
    private WebView ww;
    private String url = null;;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG, "WebFragment onCreateView");

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);
            this.ww = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.ww);
            // WebView settings here...
            this.ww.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            if (this.url != null)
                this.ww.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void loadUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        if (this.ww != null)
            this.ww.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

By using the menu of my activity, I can switch to one or the other fragments.
Obviously, I will need some kind of controller to manage the fragment and a "bridge" to populate the activity's events but it seems to be ok.

Is it ok to keep multiple fragments (each one contain a webview) like that in memory ?
I need to keep the webview and their content but the fragment is only use in this case as a container.

Still open to some comments or suggestions.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In one of my projects, I also have to manage multiple webviews, and I *Manage manually a framelayout by removing and adding the selected webview*.

Comment: Hi Neevek, so you clear the framelayout and add your webview each time?

Comment: Yes, as you state in your question.